# Not uninstalling previous matplotlib version

Tags: python, matplotlib, upgrade

I have a problem upgrading matplotlib.

The current version is 1.1.1.

I am on Mavericks, with a virtualenv activated. When I do

```
 pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

it downloads a bunch of stuff, then says

```
 Found existing installation: matplotlib 1.1.1
      Not uninstalling matplotlib at /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
      Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python, outside environment /Users/1111/
      .virtualenvs/chronicl

 Successfully installed matplotlib pytz numpy python-dateutil
```

But doesn't upgrade my matplotlib. The `pip freeze` says I still have 1.1.1. Whan can be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to uninstall and then install, instead of upgrading?

Comment: I tried uninstalling inside the virtualenv. Didn't work. After your comment I took a deep breath and uninstalled it globally, then installed the latest version. That worked. :)

Comment: That's good to hear!